# Difference using deinit and defer for resource deallocation in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-management

I'm learning more about Swift and came across the `defer` statement recently, which seems really intriguing to me. However I don't really understand it's purpose. Coming from C++ I would have implemented the same functionality using deallocation function and as a matter of fact, as Swift is ARC, it can do the same.

Let's say `FooData` and `BarData` both work with data that needs to deallocated.

```
class FooData {
    deinit {
        print("FooData being deallocated")
    }
}

class BarData {
}

func baz() -> Int {
    var a = FooData()
    var b = BarData()
    defer { print("BarData being deallocated") }

    /* sensitive operations that could throw at any time */

    return 0
}

baz()
// BarData being deallocated
// FooData being deallocated
```

So what's the advantage of the `defer` approach over the `deinit` approach? Just thinking about using `defer` for anything besides resource cleanup makes my head hurt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing as different but there are not, `defer` was introduced by Apple as a safe and easy way to handle the clean up before returning, but `defer` only works for scopes. So let me explain better, if you have some scope defined inside a function an the variable you have created exist only inside the scope you cannot access from the `deinit`, for example:

```
func resizeImage(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {
   // ...
   let dataSize: Int = ...
   let destData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(dataSize)
   defer {
      destData.dealloc(dataSize)
   }

   var destBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: destData, ...)

   // scale the image from sourceBuffer to destBuffer
   var error = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&sourceBuffer, &destBuffer, ...)
   guard error == kvImageNoError 
      else { return nil }

   // create a CGImage from the destBuffer
   guard let destCGImage = vImageCreateCGImageFromBuffer(&destBuffer,   &format, ...) 
        else { return nil }
   // ...
}
```

In this case it doesn't make sense define the variable `destData` as global and we need to deallocate once we finish of work with it, so `defer` it's the choice.

I think `deinit` it can be used for more global scope, for example when you implement the Key-Value Observer using `NSNotificationCenter` or something else you need.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 3):

Using **defer** inside a method means that its work will be executed as the method is exiting.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Step 1")
    myFunc()
    print("Step 5")
}

func myFunc() {
    print("Step 2")
    defer { print("Step 3") }
    print("Step 4")
}
```

"Step 1", "Step 2", "Step 4", "Step 3", "Step 5" – steps 3 and 4 are switched because 3 is deferred until the myFunc() method ends, i.e. when it goes out of scope programmatically.

---

About **deinit**, this is used to run code before deinitialization. The deinit code is run automatically. Deinitializers are called automatically, just before instance deallocation takes place. You are not allowed to call a deinitializer yourself.

```
class Item {
    init() {
    print("init called")
    }
    deinit {
    // Called whenever class stops existing.
    print("deinit called")
    }
}

// Create optional Item variable.
var i: Item? = Item()
// Set optional to nil to force deinit.
i = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

In programming some functions always appear in pairs. For example, opening a connection and closing that connection, locking a mutex and unlocking a mutex, incrementing a counter, decrementing a counter, allocating memory, deallocating memory.

The pattern usually looks like this:

```
lock()
... do something ...
unlock()
```

The middle part can be complicated and long. There can be returns (e.g. for failed preconditions and Swift recommends this pattern with its `guard`). Sometimes it's very hard not to forget to include that `unlock()` in all execution paths.

One way to solve the situation nicely is using a helper function:

```
func doSomething() {
   ... do something with returns ...
}

lock()
doSomething()
unlock()
```

but that's not always possible, e.g. when you have several nested objects.

In C the same pattern was often solved with `goto`:

```
x = malloc(...);
y = malloc(...);
if (!precondition) {
   goto end;
}

... some code ...

end:
free(y);
free(x);
```

Modern languages came with a better approach which in Swift is implemented using `defer` (you can also find `defer` in Go, for example).

```
lock()
defer {
   unlock()
}
... some code ...
```

This approach has several benefits:

1. You can have the calls together, which increases readability and makes it very hard to forget the second call.
2. All returns, precondition checks, error handling will leave the code in correct state because `unlock` will be always called correctly. This is similar to `finally` in exception handling in Java (and other languages)

If you are asking about the difference from `deinit`, it works in a similar way. However `defer` can work in functions while `deinit` works only for classes.

Also note that you could reimplement `defer` using `deinit` but the usage would be more complicated and the behavior less predictable.

Answer (score 1):

defer could be called conditionally what is impossible to implement with deinit

```
var i = 1
func foo()->Int {
    if i == 1 {
        defer {
            i = 0
        }
    }
    return i + 1
}
print("foo:", foo(), "i:", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a database transaction. You want to close the connection when you're done, but you want to keep the object around to reinstate connections in the future:

```
stuct foo {

    let db = Database()

    func useDatabase() throws {
        let connection = db.openConnection()
        defer {
            // close conenction, but keep db around for future use
            connection.close
        }

        try connection.thisCanThrow()
    }
}
```

This is just one example, but there are many like it. In particular, a lot of cases arise where you want to model the restricted lifespan of a state, without binding it tightly to an object's life time.

C++ heavily relies on [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Swift is certainly capable of adhering to the same paradigm, but it can also go beyond it with `defer`.

Comment: However in this case you could tie the lifespan of the connection to the connection object. The database would be kept for later use, the connection would close.

Comment: Yes, you can. RAII is certainly capable, but as this shows, there are other ways.

Comment: Now consider the situation where the class/struct that needs to be closed isn't yours, thus you can't modify its `deinit`. Then what? You'd have to write a wrapper object. It's cumbersome.

Comment: But as soon as you use the object several, it makes it worth it, you don't have to remember the `defer` every time you use it.

Comment: Not if the particular code you want to defer is specific to its call site, and not a general behavior of the object it would otherwise be tied to. For example, what if I want a message to be logged when a scope exists. That's not a behavior I want permanently bound to the `deinit` for everyone to use.